# Java:Convert date in UTC to local time zone

Tags: java, date, utc

I have date which is stored in db in UTC timezone. have to convert this date to systems local timezone. I'd looked into all other questions in stackoverflow but non of them works for me. Please can any one help me with this.
I need output in java.utils.Date only as startAt() method of quartz scheduler accepts Only Date.

Comment: If the scheduler only accepts `Date`, then there's no time zone to be concerned with - a `Date` represents an instant in time. I suspect that if you provide more context we'll be able to help you more...

Comment: @dhananjay which java version are you using?

Comment: Actually Date is stored into the db by ROR it converts the date to UTC format before storing it. So when I fetch the date from db and create the Date object the time gets change from what I've entered as coz its timezone is changed. So I need a way which will get the date stored in db in UTC timezone and convert it into the local timezone

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to get the date from the database. Are you specifying there that the date in the database is in UTC?

Comment: reminderQueues.setStartDate(rs.getTimestamp("rq.start_date")); where rs is ResultSet.Yeah the date is stored in db in UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into StackOverFlows questions find a class DateBuilder of quartz which helps to translate the timezone

```
Date startDate = DateBuilder.translateTime(job.getStartDate(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You do *not* need to apply a time zone.

## Details

A `Date` already has a time zone: UTC. It represents a specific moment, a point on the timeline. You would only apply a time zone for display to user in the user’s preferred [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). An alarm set for 6 AM UTC fires at 7 AM in `Europe/Paris` and 11:30 AM in `Asia/Kolkata` — the very same simultaneous moment.

### `Date` is UTC

The `java.util.Date` class already uses [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). You cannot adjust that object to another time zone. That class is simply a wrapper around a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. Do not be distracted by the confusing behavior of its `toString` method that applies the JVM’s current default time zone in rendering the String; the internal value is in UTC<sup>†</sup>.

So what you ask ( start with a `Date`, adjust to a local time zone, and render a `Date`) is impossible and makes no sense.

I suggest you do some searching and studying of other date-time questions on StackOverflow to learn the concepts. Search specifically for these Java classes: `Instant` , `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime`.

### Conversion

You can convert to java.time when needing to interface with old code not yet updated to the java.time types. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();  // UTC.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );  // Same moment, but different wall-clock time.
```

And you can convert from java.time classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 );  // 2016-01-23. No time zone at all.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 6 , 0 , 0 );  // 06:00:00. No time zone at all.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime( ld , lt , z );
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();  // UTC.

// Convert from modern classes to legacy class.
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

---

<sup>†</sup>The `java.util.Date` actually *does* have a time zone set down in its bowels. But that zone has no setter and no getter method. For our purposes here, we can ignore it. Confusing? Yes. One of many poor design choices made in the early Java date-time classes. And one of many reasons to avoid these classes. Stick with java.time classes only.

Comment: I'd looked into almost every question on StackOverFlow but non of them fulfill my requirement. Now that you are saying timezone of Date can't be changed then the question is how would I schedule the scheduler to execute at different timezone which accepts only Date. :(

Comment: @dhananjaysengraphwar You are missing the key idea: **You do *not* need to apply a time zone**. A `Date` already has a time zone: UTC. It represents a specific moment, a point on the timeline. You would only apply a time zone for display to user in the user’s preferred [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). An alarm set for 6 AM UTC fires at 7 AM in `Europe/Paris` and 11:30 AM in `Asia/Kolkata` — the very same simultaneous moment. Perhaps you should edit your Question to explain more about your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and sharing details with me I'm glad

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

```
    DateFormat localFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    localFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));


    Date locaTime = new Date(localFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) from java 8. I use below code to get the local date time from unix timestamp. There might be other methods to get it from the format you want.

```
Date.from(LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(unixTimestamp, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate());
```

Comment: Wrong classes to use here. The `LocalDateTime` lacks any concept of time zone or offset.