# Convert UTC time as per offset in java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, calendar, timezone-offset

I'm getting a time & offset in String.

Time is in UTC and I have to convert this time as per offset and then assign it to a `Calendar` object.

The problem is that I'm using `plusHours()` method of `OffsetDateTime` class. I'm getting same results.

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-03-26T06:00:00Z" ) ;
odtB.plusHours(2);
System.out.println(odtB);
```

For example if my date is `"2018-03-26T06:00:00Z"` and offset/Timezone value is "+02:00" how to change it for getting output `"2018-03-26T08:00:00Z"`?

Comment: You seem to be confused. Which input do you talk about? Time input without offset info or with, i.e. "2019-01-16T00:05:00.000" versus "2019-01-16T00:05:00.000Z" or "2019-01-16T00:05:00.000+00:00"? If your time input already has an offset info then no need to combine it with any extra offset info because you can then directly interprete it as instant and translate/migrate it to old `java.util.Date`-object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java:Convert date in UTC to local time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016206/javaconvert-date-in-utc-to-local-time-zone)

Comment: `2018-03-26T08:00:00Z` is two hours later in UTC (`Z` means UTC). Is this what you want? Or rather `2018-03-26T08:00:00+02:00`, that is, the original point in time with the wall-clock hour of your offset?

Answer (score 5):

First things first: the `plusHours` method returns **another** `OffsetDateTime`, but it doesn't change the original one. To get the result of the method, you need to assign it to a variable:

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-26T06:00:00Z");
odtB = odtB.plusHours(2);
System.out.println(odtB);
```

This will print:

> 2018-03-26T08:00Z

Now to your question:

> *For example if my date is "2018-03-26T06:00:00Z" and offset/Timezone value is "+02:00" how to change it for getting output "2018-03-26T08:00:00Z"?*

I think you're mistaking some concepts. The `Z` in the end is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), and it's the same as `+00:00`.

Both the dates above (`2018-03-26T06:00:00Z` and `2018-03-26T08:00Z`) are in UTC, and each one represents a **different** instant (a different point in the timeline). When you call `plusHours(2)`, the result is another `OffsetDateTime` that's 2 hours after the first one.

If you want to **convert** the `OffsetDateTime` to another offset, you shouldn't add hours to it. You should do this:

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-26T06:00:00Z");
// convert to offset +02:00
odtB = odtB.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
```

Now the result is `2018-03-26T08:00+02:00` - note that the offset changed from Z to +02:00, but both (`2018-03-26T08:00+02:00` and `2018-03-26T06:00:00Z`) represent **the same instant** (the same point in the timeline).

This can become clearer if you compare the results using `isEqual` (a method that [checks if the dates correspond to the same instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.OffsetDateTime-)):

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-26T06:00:00Z");

// add hours
OffsetDateTime twoHoursLater = odtB.plusHours(2);
System.out.println(odtB.isEqual(twoHoursLater)); // false

// convert to offset +02:00
OffsetDateTime sameInstantDifferentOffset = odtB.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
System.out.println(odtB.isEqual(sameInstantDifferentOffset)); // true
```

---

To convert to other offsets, such as `+05:30`, you just need to change the offset used. Instead of `ZoneOffset.ofHours(2)`, you can use one of those:

```
ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30)
ZoneOffset.of("+05:30")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-01-16T00:05:00.000" ) ;
odtB = odtB.plusHours(2);
System.out.println(odtB);
```

Comment: Hi Mareks, Thanks it works. Is it the correct approach to deal with offset values or there is anyother way to change time as per offset.

Comment: suppose if timezone is +5:30 how to deal with it.

Comment: I assume you need to use ToLocalTime instead, if you have UTC as source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As the code stands, it throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-01-16T00:05:00.000' could not be parsed at index 23`. With the string from the question it runs, but gives the wrong result, `2018-03-26T08:00Z`, which is in UTC (denoted by the Z at the end), which was not what I understood was asked for. And your link to .NET documentation is hardly relevant.

Comment: Sorry, just now read in the title you had Java example. Too many overflow answers a day :). I assume you got your answer at the end of the day, right?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to convert the date-time in your string — here March 26 at 6 AM — to the same point in time in your local time zone at UTC+2, so 8 AM (and not UTC). You aren’t really doing it the correct way. Instead do:

```
    ZoneOffset myOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(2);
    odtB = odtB.withOffsetSameInstant(myOffset);
    System.out.println(odtB);
```

Output:

> 2018-03-26T08:00+02:00

Still better, rather then relying on an offset, use a real time zone, for example:

```
    ZoneId myZone = ZoneId.of("Africa/Kigali");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = odtB.atZoneSameInstant(myZone);
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

> 2018-03-26T08:00+02:00[Africa/Kigali]

If you do want an `OffsetDateTime`, I still recommend converting through the relevant `ZoneId` as above and then just convering back to `OffsetDateTime`:

```
    odtB = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(odtB);
```

> 2018-03-26T08:00+02:00

However you said that you were to assign it to a `Calendar`. The easiest and most correct way to do that also goes through the `ZonedDateTime`:

```
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

As I hope you were aware, the `Calendar` class is long outdated. Still maybe you need a `Calendar` object for a legacy API that you cannot change or just don’t want to change just now.

If you wanted a different offset, you *might* just create that:

```
    ZoneOffset myOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(5, 30);
```

However I still recommend you use a proper time zone, for example:

```
    ZoneId myZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
```

### What went wrong in your code?

I suspect that you’ve got two bugs:

- Adding 2 hours to your `OffsetDateTime` in UTC gives you two hours later in UTC. I gather you neither wanted two hours later nor a time in UTC.
- As others have said, `plusHours` returns a *new* `OffsetDateTime` with the new value. You seem to be ignoring the return value, effectively discarding the result. The method needs to return a new object because an `OffsetDateTime` is immutable.

**EDIT:** I had neither read your question properly at first, neither is it very clear. I have changed the answer so it now answers what I think you mean.